# jQuery dynamically added <select> elements give a warning on click

Tags: jquery, html

When dynamically added `<select>`(using `jQuery`) elements are clicked i'm prompted with a **violation** warning:

> [Violation] Added non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking 'mousewheel' event. Consider marking event handler as 'passive' to make the page more responsive.

Here is the code: [codepen](https://codepen.io/emanuelones/pen/jJJRoN)

Why am i getting that warning since i don't bind any kind of event listeners to those new `<select>` elements? And is there a way to avoid that?

Thnak you!

Comment: I'm not seeing any errors

Comment: @Hybrid click on "Add Select" and then click on one of the `<select>` elements. Only at this point the Violation is prompted

Comment: I did that, and am still seeing no errors. For reference I am using the newest version of Chrome

Comment: I am too but i also do get the warning...

Comment: Did you search the warning, plenty of info on it....

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is a new [passive option](https://github.com/WICG/EventListenerOptions/blob/gh-pages/explainer.md) that can be passed to event handlers which will improve scrolling and silence the warning. Here is a [bit more information](https://medium.com/@devlucky/about-passive-event-listeners-224ff620e68c).

Example implementation:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var x = 5;

    document.querySelector('#add-select').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
     for(var n = 0; n < x; ++ n) {
        $('.dynamic-select').append('<div class="s"><select><option value="' + n + '">' + n + '</option></select></div>');
   }
    }, {passive: true})
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<button type="button" id="add-select">Add Select</button>
</div>

<div class="dynamic-select"></div>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but unfortunately the error keeps popping up :(